# How to delete old verison of android studio without losting the existing project on old version

Tags: android-studio

I have to delete the old version of android studio to free some space in my hard disk, but I afraid if I delete it and all my project on old version will disappear either.

I'm  expecting to delete old version of android studio. And want the existing project still on my new androidstudio's version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Qvf.jpg)